# What does the @ refer to in the value to a key `task` in a YAML document for Azure?

Tags: azure-devops

Many values for the key `task` in YAML documents for Azure, seem to contain `@number`.
For example [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/index-sources-publish-symbols?view=azure-devops) is called `PublishSymbols@2`

What does the `@number` refer to?

Comment: Although the word *task* appears in the YAML spec twice, it is in the introduction, both times referring to the influence of YAML on the task of programming There is no such thing as a "YAML task".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the version of the Task.

When you're editing a pipeline in the editor, you have a little *dropdown* at the top of the task. If you change it and click "View YAML", you'll see the part after the `@` will change for your chosen version.

Fixing the version is useful, because new versions could have a different behavior or require different parameters.

Comment: so you say there is a way to use latest task version in yaml? examples?

Comment: You cant reference the latest task in the yaml, you have to provide a version number. this is only the Major version number though so any minor releases of the task will be used automatically.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#task-versions